# Extract specific variable from list

Tags: r, list, loops

I would be grateful if someone told me how to extract "ID" variable in the list "works" from the list "program 1" and convert them to data frame by using for loop.

[image: the list looks like this]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't share data in form of images, use `dput(your_list_here)` and share the output at the end of your question.

Comment: The word is used in R is *subsetting*, you will find a lot of results on Google.

Comment: `program1[[1]][[1]]`??

Answer (score 0):

We could check the structure of the list, then access the list item by name or index, example:

```
# example input
program1 <- list(list(id = 1, x = 3, works = list(1:3, list(ID = 11, 1:3, 4:6))),
                 list(id = 2, x = 4, works = list(4:6, list(ID = 22, 1:3, 4:6))))

# by index
program1[[ 1 ]][[ 3 ]][[ 2 ]][[ 1 ]]
# [1] 11

# by name
program1[[1]][["works"]][[ 2 ]][["ID"]]
# [1] 11
```

If we are using RStudio, then there is a handy point-and-click option to get items from list:

[image]

This will provide below code in the console:

```
program1[[1]][["works"]][[2]][["ID"]]
```

Lastly, from your example, it looks like we want to extract all IDs from all 875 list items, then use:

```
# get all IDs
sapply(program1, function(i) i[[ "works" ]][[ 2 ]][[ "ID"]])
# [1] 11 22
```

Comment: Thank you for your kindness. I actually make it when I tried with your example, but it didn't work accurately with my actual data. Can you come up with another solution ?